# Chrome extension open new window behind the current window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have a chrome extension which automatically open a window using 
    window.open();
when user open some specific websites.
what i want is the new window which i open from the background script through window.open() should be displayed behind the current webiste opened by the user.

i have tried window.open properties like alwaysLowered=1, z-lock=1 etc. but not working.
Also tried.....

```
var w = window.open('url');
if(w){
w.blur();
window.focus();
}
```

all these have no effect on chrome. can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the handle to the opened window (returned by `window.open`), you can use the **[`chrome.windows` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html)**'s methods **[`create`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)** and **[`update`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-update)**:

**In *background.js*:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({ url: "http://www.google.com/" }, function(win) {
        chrome.windows.update(win.id, { focused: false });
    });
});
```

<sub>Theoretically, passing the `focused: false` property in the **createInfo** argument should achieve the same result in one step, but it is not working for me with Chrome version 31.0.1650.57 on Windows.</sub>

---

**UPDATE:**
The above code seems to not "blur" the window on Macs. To overcome this (while determining the position and size of the new window - as per OP's comment) use the following code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({ 
        url: "http://www.google.com/",
        width:  430,
        height: 150,
        top:    top_popup,
        left:   left_popup
    }, function(win) {
        chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. it works fine with windows chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m, but not working in mac chrome Version 31.0.1650.63.

Comment: Interesting ! Instead of trying to blur the created window, you could try to focus the original (but I don't have a MAC available for testing). E.g. try changing `chrome.windows.update(win.id, { focused: false });` to `chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true });`

Comment: Did you try what I proposed in my comment above ? Did it work ?

Comment: Yes i have tried it.  its working. it actually does not applies the width and height parameter for the popup, instead it applies it to the other window.

Comment: What width and height ?

Comment: the process is when somebody open chrome and type specific url(mysite.com), i automatically open a popup. Actually i have applied width, height, top and bottom for the popup     chrome.windows.create({ url: site_url+"/myurl.html"}, function(win) { chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true, width:430, height:150, top:top_popup, left:left_popup});}); but this width and height etc.. parameters is getting applied to the window which has opened at the begning, but not to the popup(new window).

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(winCurrent){
        chrome.windows.create({url:url, function(win){
            chrome.windows.update(winCurrent.id, {focused: true});
        });
    });
```

Try this, its fast so viewer doesn't feel much