# Open new window in background using Chrome API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window

I have a content script that sends a basic message (a link) to my background.js of of my extension.

My question is how can I open that link in the background with chrome.windows.create without it gaining focus at all, also when i minimize chrome and another link gets opened I dont want chrome to gain focus again.

```
//Opens received link //background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: message.link
    });
});
```

Edit:
I have added this to my code for creating the new window and it doesnt switch to it but my question is, is there any way that can all happen in the background? like without any window showing up, not even minimized?

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url: message.link,
    type: "normal",
    state: "minimized"
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/20400893/834 ?

Comment: None of those worked for me.

Comment: @Tyrone, make sure you tried that without browserAction call.......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension open new window behind the current window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399798/chrome-extension-open-new-window-behind-the-current-window)

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(winCurrent){
        chrome.windows.create({url:message.link}, function(win){
            chrome.windows.update(winCurrent.id, {focused: true});
        });
    });
```

Use `getCurrent` to get your current window, create a new window and shift focus back to the previous window (`winCurrent`). The process is fast so viewer doesn't feel much.

Comment: it works but the user still sees some flickering even in very fast computers